# Send QDataStream through QTcpSocket or QSslSocket

Tags: qt, qt4, qtcpsocket, qbytearray, qsslsocket

I want to send serialized data through ssl or tcp socket. QIODevice::write doesn't send QDataStream but only char* and QByteArray.

Is there a way I can send serialized data through socket? Or how can I convert QDataStream to QByteArray?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `QIODevice` to the `QDataStream` constructor.  This will allow you to write to the device through the stream.